# SUDO user permission to modify /etc/network/interfaces file via SSH without exiting from his home?

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo

How could i give to a no SUDO user permission to modify /etc/network/interfaces file via SSH without exiting from his home?

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of options and the first one is to use `tee` to replace the existing file. For that we first update sudo with `visudo` and assign the `tee` command to anyone in the `sudo` group.

```
%sudo ALL = tee /etc/network/interfaces
```

Running the command where `filename` is the file that contains the new content.

```
$ cat filename | sudo tee /etc/network/interfaces
```

A second option is to use `sudoedit` and we do the same as before and add the `sudoedit` command to `sudo` group.

```
%sudo ALL = sudoedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

Now we can simply and safely edit the file.

```
$ sudoedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

The first option is handy for automated tasks and the second one for manual actions to update a file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, i created a jailed user with the jailkit (https://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/index.html#intro) and after that i created a hard link to the folder network.